# How to auto-restart IIS App Pool after RapidFailProtection

Tags: iis

I have an IIS website.

- The AppPool is set to `autoStart = true` (so the AppPool starts running on a server Reboot).
- The AppPool is set to `startMode = alwaysRunning` (so the website starts running when the AppPool starts).
- The AppPool has default rapidFailProtection enabled. (So 5 site crashes in 5 minutes will stop the AppPool).

I occasionally discover that the AppPool has stopped, and I've recently realised that it generally means that there was some sort of network failure. When that happens, my app fails on startup ... which means it trips the rapidFailProtection. (Seems sensible).

But then the AppPool is stopped and nothing starts it back up again. So once the network failure event has ended ... it's still down :(

It feels like this must be a standard scenario, and thus I'd expect a standard setting solution. Some sort of "restart the AppPool 2 hours after RapidFailProtection" or something.

The absolute ideal would be for RapidFailProtection to initiate an exponential backoff process, but that sounds a bit optimistic :D

Comment: This is not a supported configuration; however, you can configure an executable to be called when a rapid-fire shutdown stops the app-pool.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting like "Restart AppPool 2 hours after RapidFailProtection". Rapid-Fail Protection is enabled by default, what it does is check for a specified number of hard failures, the default is 5 failures within 5 minutes, then the application pool will crash and not restart automatically. That's how it works.

As an alternative, you can set up a PowerShell script like the below and set it up as a scheduled task that runs periodically so that it periodically checks the status of the application pool and restarts it if it stops. Of course, you can also set the specified conditions to trigger the task. For example, you can have it execute on a schedule, at login, at idle, at startup, or when a specific event occurs. You can refer this [article](https://kloudvm.medium.com/how-to-monitor-iis-application-pools-using-powershell-script-for-free-in-2-minutes-e47dcf0510f5).

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
set-Location IIS:\AppPools
$ApplicationPools = dir
foreach ($item in $ApplicationPools)
{
$ApplicationPoolName = $item.Name
$ApplicationPoolStatus = $item.state
Write-Host "$ApplicationPoolName -> $ApplicationPoolStatus"

if($ApplicationPoolStatus -ne "Started")
{
Write-Host "-----> $ApplicationPoolName found stopped."
Start-WebAppPool -Name $ApplicationPoolName
Write-Host "-----> $ApplicationPoolName started."
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rapid fail also has a Shutdown Executable setting that could be used to call the script from @YurongDai's answer.
to run a script as an executable you need to do the following:
Install-Module ps2exe
Invoke-PS2EXE C:\shell\path\shell.ps1 C:\Shell\executabe\path\ExecutableShell.exe
from:[article](https://helpcenter.cameyo.com/support/solutions/articles/80000737075-how-to-turn-a-powershell-script-into-an-executable)